# Getting hiccup noise from Shoutcast

Tags: windows-phone-7, streaming, shoutcast

I'm trying to read Shoutcast stream and then play it using MediaStreamSource. Here is the excellent open source [project](http://shoutstreamsource.codeplex.com/) that saved lot of my time. After little bit modification I'm able to hear perfect sound. But the problem is I'm getting a periodic blip/hiccup kind of noise.

Any idea how I can stop that noise. I thought its may be Shoutcast sends some metadata in interval but don't find out how to stop that. Tried with `request.Headers["Icy-MetaData"] = "0";`
But it doesn't fix my problem either. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit1:**
I did some more investigation. I read my stream data for 2-3 mins and found that there are lot of 'zero' byte in that stream. Here is the list of index of '0' byte

92  247  359  1208  1904  2037  2227  2397  2536  2694  2740  2863  2952  3048  3110  3689  3994  4027  4098  4218  4730  4830  4943  5029  5115  5248  5315  5358  5666  6084  6375  6873  6920  7441  7660  7700  7756  8174  8254  8614  9010  9018  9025  9039  9541  9846.....

Is it because httpwebrequest slow download/failed to download or Shoutcast itself sending those zero bytes? Also does this '0' bytes causing that hiccup noise?

**Edit2:**
Here is few line of code of how I'm getting response from shoutcast

```
        HttpWebRequest request = result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
        HttpWebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(result) as HttpWebResponse;     
        r = response.GetResponseStream();
        ShoutcastHeader(r);
```

And here is my ShoutcastHeader method definition:

```
        StreamReader headerReader = new StreamReader(r);
        bool headerIsDone = false;
        while (!headerIsDone)
        {
            string headerLine = headerReader.ReadLine();

            if (headerLine.StartsWith("icy-name:"))
            {
                StationName = headerLine.Substring(9);
            }
            else if (headerLine.StartsWith("icy-genre:"))
            {
                Genre = headerLine.Substring(10);
            }
            else if (headerLine.StartsWith("icy-br:"))
            {
                BitRate = short.Parse(headerLine.Substring(7));
            }
            else if (headerLine.StartsWith("icy-metaint:"))
            {
                MetaInt = int.Parse(headerLine.Substring(12)) * 1111084;
                MetadataAvailable = true;
            }
            else if (headerLine.Equals(""))
                headerIsDone = true;
        }
```

And here is the response in headerReader

ICY 200 OK
icy-notice1:
This stream requires [Winamp](http://www.winamp.com/)
icy-notice2:SHOUTcast Distributed Network Audio Server/Linux v1.9.93atdn
icy-name:Bollywood & Beyond - Radio NRI 24/7
icy-genre:Indian Hindi Tamil Telugu Malayalam Desi
icy-url:http://www.radionri.com
content-type:audio/mpeg
icy-pub:1
icy-br:128

Also I have places the stream bytes in my skydrive share [location](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=22d64e162daa62ac&resid=22D64E162DAA62AC!401&parid=22D64E162DAA62AC!101&authkey=!AMFWJABokydEmeM).

Comment: I've observed the same thing happening on Radio RIP, an Android app. It's intermittent though. I'm curious about the answers to this

Comment: For me its very annoying, that noise is coming in every 10 sec.

Comment: on the android app it is every 1 or 2 seconds. Once it starts, it's there until I hard close the app and start it up again.

Comment: Does it blip if you're on wifi?  Is it a buffering issue?

Comment: A value of `0` is perfectly normal in an MP3 stream.  It does sound to me like the metadata is still getting in there.  To a packet capture and post the first meg of it or so online.  Post all the request/response headers here in your post.

Comment: Thanks Brad. I have updated my question with required information. Please let me know if you need any more data. Thanks again

Comment: @Derek: I tried connecting LAN connection, but observed same issue.

Comment: @PritamKarmakar, You've got the response headers there, but we need to see your **request** headers, as sent to the server.  Use Wireshark and do a packet capture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Based on this thread](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/68216/587270.aspx) it looks like the hiccups are the header information being resent periodically. There is an [issue on ShoutStreamSource project referencing this](http://shoutstreamsource.codeplex.com/workitem/568) too:

> "The current implementation does not discard the mp3headers after the first one has been parsed. This causes hicups in the sound coming from the stream, and will be fixed in the near future."

However at the time of this answer it looks like the project was put on hold. Hopefully you or someone else can add this functionality. At least knowing what the problem is should help with a solution.

Comment: Thanks. But looks like people have fixed it somehow. I see one streamer in wp7 marketplace and it is working pretty good with shoutcast

Comment: While I understand that you want to fix the hiccup issue, this is the answer to what is causing the problem. I think if you want help fixing the ShoutStreamSource project then you might want to ask a new question with information regarding the issue in that project. Or at least edit your question, as it would otherwise be confusing. As for other apps, they may not be using this library or if they are they may not have shared their fix.